# extract number from http request

Tags: c

I want to extract some number from HTTP Get requests in C.
for example if my HTTP request is like:

```
GET /getUIKVal?mdn=9860436150 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.end.point
```

I want number 9860436150 to be printed as output.
I have already tried with sscanf() and atoi()

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code ?

Comment: Anyway, try `strstr` to find marker `mdn=` and then use `scanf / %s` to read until the next white space.

Comment: @StephanLechner yes it worked with strstr. Will paste the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `sscanf` like below.

```
char* line = "GET /getUIKVal?mdn=9860436150 HTTP/1.1";
long long val ;

int ret = sscanf(line, "%*[^=]=%lld",&val);
printf("%lld\n", val) ;
```

Where `%*[^=]=` will read and discard the string until it reaches `=` 
and `%ld` will read actual number in `val`.

Comment: Adding on: OP will need to use a long integer, as depicted in this answer. Perhaps that was the real problem since OP did not post code.

Comment: @nicomp Yes can be.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I am not getting correct value with this. I got 2147483647 as output

Comment: @Neha I'm getting the exact output. Are you missing something? How are you reading/printing it? You are supposed to use `%ld`.

Comment: Check the result of  `sscanf`; otherwise acess to `val` may introduce undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Neha What `sscanf` is returning? It is supposed to return `2`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar. Yes it is returning 2. I have copied your code as it is. Gettiing a constant output 2147483647.

Comment: @Neha Maybe you are having overflow try declaring `val`  as `long long val` and use `%lld` to read and print.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strstr` to identify marker `mdn=` and then either scan a number or a string. Note that for scanning the number you don't need to copy the respective contents; The code below shows how:

```
const char* content = "GET /getUIKVal?mdn=9860436150 HTTP/1.1";
const char* startOfNumber = strstr(content,"mdn=");
if (startOfNumber) {
   startOfNumber += strlen("mdn=");
   long number;
   if (scanf("%ld",&number)==1) {
      printf("the number is... %ld", number);
   } else {
      printf("no valid number after 'mdn='");      
   }
} else {
      printf("marker 'mdn=' not found.");      
}
```

I actually prefer the `strstr`-solution over a solution where `scanf` identifies both the marker and the number because it is hard to reason about syntax errors then.