# Extract substring with a variable field C with sscanf

Tags: c

I would like to extract a particular field from an HTTP request/response.

i.e.

```
...
Server: gws
Content-Length: 224
X-XSS-Protection: 0
...
```

as a *char* * : I'd like to place just '224' for example into some variable.

I have code like:

```
int extract_content_size(Buffer *header)
{
    char* line = "GET /Content-Length: 224\n";
int val ;

int ret = sscanf(line, "%*[^Content-Length: ]%[%d]%*[^\n]",&val);
printf("%s",line);
printf("THE EXTRACTED THING IS %lld\n", val) ;
    return ret;
}
```

I.e. Discard everything up to

Which is somewhat copied from a similar question:

[extract number from http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625329/extract-number-from-http-request)

(i.e. this little part is very well documented)!

Specifically my output is:

```
GET /Content-Length: 224
THE EXTRACTED THING IS 925
```

I believe the regex could be at fault here; but following guides has made it seem correct.

Im really only concerned with the content_length here.

---

Here is some further detail:

on

```
Location: http://www.google.com/imghp
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Date: Sun, 22 Sep 2019 22:05:47 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 224
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2019-09-22-22; expires=Tue, 22-Oct-2019 22:05:47 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; SameSite=none
Set-Cookie: NID=188=VSRygM_9FrfzeRwgcE8mFcDzXgPD86b7oRDIIE8EaIyIrkBbNFbs_cWkKWb47Fb_tmYY7lKL9xmjKUMy8yhb9Jpm-Bkh4-NXDqHSFW1HD_BddPfdGNqLG_DHz-7dMTedVaV4_SVaETs_gPzDi8oxh8XB_z5UYQIUD0EcK-86qFI; expires=Mon, 23-Mar-2020 22:05:47 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/imghp">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Which is a full HEAD request for www.google.com /images

The output is still incorrect using:

int ret = sscanf ( header->data, "GET /Content-Length:%d", &val);

specifically:

```
THE EXTRACTED THING IS 3
```

Comment: It works for the test case. I added the full part to the question. Thank you

Comment: What value is `sscanf` returning? I suspect it's zero, which is why `val` is a nonsense value. That means the string you want to scan doesn't match the specified format.

Comment: it is indeed Zero!

Comment: Verify whether `header->data` is in the intended format. If not, you either have to (1) do more preprocessing or (2) change the sscanf format string. As a side note, it's always recommended to check the return value of a function that may fail. It helps identify bugs faster.

Comment: I added an answer with a solution, Thank you